Positioning Of Labels Is Wrong
I am writing a user interface for a robot. I made 3 usercontrol tabs for dashboard, manuel control and guide. The problem is label's positions are changing when I start the program. Code of designer main form and a tap is here
form1:
namespace ELÇİ___Yer_İstasyonu
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///Gerekli tasarımcı değişkeni.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///Kullanılan tüm kaynakları temizleyin.
        /// </summary>
        ///<param name="disposing">yönetilen kaynaklar dispose edilmeliyse doğru; aksi halde yanlış.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
        #region Windows Form Designer üretilen kod
        /// <summary>
        /// Tasarımcı desteği için gerekli metot - bu metodun 
        ///içeriğini kod düzenleyici ile değiştirmeyin.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.pictureBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.pictureBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.buttonGuide = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.buttonManuel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.buttonRobot = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.panelContainer = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox4)).BeginInit();
            this.panel2.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox3)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(107)))), ((int)(((byte)(166)))));
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox4);
            this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1308, 63);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(74, 15);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(815, 45);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "YOMRA GENÇLİK MERKEZİ KTU UZAY S-1";
            // 
            // pictureBox4
            // 
            this.pictureBox4.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox4.Image")));
            this.pictureBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.pictureBox4.Name = "pictureBox4";
            this.pictureBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(74, 66);
            this.pictureBox4.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            this.pictureBox4.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox4.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // panel2
            // 
            this.panel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(51)))), ((int)(((byte)(63)))), ((int)(((byte)(72)))));
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox2);
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox3);
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonGuide);
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonManuel);
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.buttonRobot);
            this.panel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
            this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 63);
            this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
            this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1308, 63);
            this.panel2.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // pictureBox2
            // 
            this.pictureBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.pictureBox2.Enabled = false;
            this.pictureBox2.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox2.Image")));
            this.pictureBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(480, 7);
            this.pictureBox2.Name = "pictureBox2";
            this.pictureBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(56, 50);
            this.pictureBox2.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            this.pictureBox2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.pictureBox2.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox3
            // 
            this.pictureBox3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.pictureBox3.Enabled = false;
            this.pictureBox3.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox3.Image")));
            this.pictureBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(694, 6);
            this.pictureBox3.Name = "pictureBox3";
            this.pictureBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(56, 50);
            this.pictureBox3.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            this.pictureBox3.TabIndex = 2;
            this.pictureBox3.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
            this.pictureBox1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image")));
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(265, 6);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(56, 50);
            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // buttonGuide
            // 
            this.buttonGuide.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(682, 0);
            this.buttonGuide.Name = "buttonGuide";
            this.buttonGuide.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(207, 63);
            this.buttonGuide.TabIndex = 4;
            this.buttonGuide.Text = "Kılavuz";
            this.buttonGuide.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.buttonGuide.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonGuide_Click);
            // 
            // buttonManuel
            // 
            this.buttonManuel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.buttonManuel.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.buttonManuel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(469, 0);
            this.buttonManuel.Name = "buttonManuel";
            this.buttonManuel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(207, 63);
            this.buttonManuel.TabIndex = 3;
            this.buttonManuel.Text = "Manuel";
            this.buttonManuel.TextImageRelation = System.Windows.Forms.TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
            this.buttonManuel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.buttonManuel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonManuel_Click);
            // 
            // buttonRobot
            // 
            this.buttonRobot.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
            this.buttonRobot.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
            this.buttonRobot.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.buttonRobot.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System;
            this.buttonRobot.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            this.buttonRobot.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(256, 0);
            this.buttonRobot.Name = "buttonRobot";
            this.buttonRobot.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(207, 63);
            this.buttonRobot.TabIndex = 2;
            this.buttonRobot.Text = "             Gösterge Pabeli";
            this.buttonRobot.TextImageRelation = System.Windows.Forms.TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
            this.buttonRobot.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.buttonRobot.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonRobot_Click);
            // 
            // panelContainer
            // 
            this.panelContainer.AutoSize = true;
            this.panelContainer.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            this.panelContainer.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.panelContainer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 126);
            this.panelContainer.Name = "panelContainer";
            this.panelContainer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1308, 638);
            this.panelContainer.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1308, 764);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panelContainer);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "ELÇİ - Yer İstasyonu";
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel1.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox4)).EndInit();
            this.panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox3)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();
        }
        #endregion
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonRobot;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonGuide;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonManuel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panelContainer;
    }
}

dashboard:
namespace ELÇİ___Yer_İstasyonu.UserControls
{
    partial class ucRobot
    {
        /// <summary> 
        ///Gerekli tasarımcı değişkeni.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        ///Kullanılan tüm kaynakları temizleyin.
        /// </summary>
        ///<param name="disposing">yönetilen kaynaklar dispose edilmeliyse doğru; aksi halde yanlış.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
        #region Bileşen Tasarımcısı üretimi kod
        /// <summary> 
        /// Tasarımcı desteği için gerekli metot - bu metodun 
        ///içeriğini kod düzenleyici ile değiştirmeyin.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.labelTemperature = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label7 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label8 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.labelChargeLevel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.labelSpeed = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.labelLoad = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.labelVoltage = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.labelCurrent = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.labelElapsedTime = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.labelActivity = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // labelTemperature
            // 
            this.labelTemperature.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.labelTemperature.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.labelTemperature.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.labelTemperature.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(566, 105);
            this.labelTemperature.Name = "labelTemperature";
            this.labelTemperature.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(77, 63);
            this.labelTemperature.TabIndex = 20;
            this.labelTemperature.Text = "---";
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(367, 260);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(167, 64);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 21;
            this.label1.Text = "Voltaj:";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.label2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.label2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(368, 438);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(166, 68);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 22;
            this.label2.Text = "Akım:";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.label3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.label3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(343, 524);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(191, 66);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 23;
            this.label3.Text = "Ağırlık:";
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this.label4.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.label4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.label4.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 609);
            this.label4.Name = "label4";
            this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(334, 66);
            this.label4.TabIndex = 24;
            this.label4.Text = "Anlık Aktivite:";
            // 
            // label5
            // 
            this.label5.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.label5.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.label5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(314, 337);
            this.label5.Name = "label5";
            this.label5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 69);
            this.label5.TabIndex = 25;
            this.label5.Text = "Batarya:";
            // 
            // label6
            // 
            this.label6.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.label6.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.label6.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(313, 105);
            this.label6.Name = "label6";
            this.label6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(221, 63);
            this.label6.TabIndex = 26;
            this.label6.Text = "Sıcaklık:";
            // 
            // label7
            // 
            this.label7.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.label7.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.label7.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.label7.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(410, 29);
            this.label7.Name = "label7";
            this.label7.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(124, 65);
            this.label7.TabIndex = 27;
            this.label7.Text = "Hız:";
            // 
            // label8
            // 
            this.label8.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.label8.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.label8.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.label8.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(382, 176);
            this.label8.Name = "label8";
            this.label8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 68);
            this.label8.TabIndex = 28;
            this.label8.Text = "Süre:";
            // 
            // labelChargeLevel
            // 
            this.labelChargeLevel.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.labelChargeLevel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.labelChargeLevel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.labelChargeLevel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(566, 337);
            this.labelChargeLevel.Name = "labelChargeLevel";
            this.labelChargeLevel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(77, 69);
            this.labelChargeLevel.TabIndex = 29;
            this.labelChargeLevel.Text = "---";
            // 
            // labelSpeed
            // 
            this.labelSpeed.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.labelSpeed.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.labelSpeed.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.labelSpeed.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(566, 29);
            this.labelSpeed.Name = "labelSpeed";
            this.labelSpeed.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(77, 65);
            this.labelSpeed.TabIndex = 30;
            this.labelSpeed.Text = "---";
            // 
            // labelLoad
            // 
            this.labelLoad.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.labelLoad.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.labelLoad.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.labelLoad.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(566, 524);
            this.labelLoad.Name = "labelLoad";
            this.labelLoad.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(77, 66);
            this.labelLoad.TabIndex = 31;
            this.labelLoad.Text = "---";
            // 
            // labelVoltage
            // 
            this.labelVoltage.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.labelVoltage.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.labelVoltage.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.labelVoltage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(566, 260);
            this.labelVoltage.Name = "labelVoltage";
            this.labelVoltage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(77, 64);
            this.labelVoltage.TabIndex = 32;
            this.labelVoltage.Text = "---";
            // 
            // labelCurrent
            // 
            this.labelCurrent.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.labelCurrent.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.labelCurrent.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.labelCurrent.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(566, 438);
            this.labelCurrent.Name = "labelCurrent";
            this.labelCurrent.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(77, 68);
            this.labelCurrent.TabIndex = 33;
            this.labelCurrent.Text = "---";
            // 
            // labelElapsedTime
            // 
            this.labelElapsedTime.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.labelElapsedTime.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.labelElapsedTime.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.labelElapsedTime.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(566, 176);
            this.labelElapsedTime.Name = "labelElapsedTime";
            this.labelElapsedTime.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(77, 68);
            this.labelElapsedTime.TabIndex = 34;
            this.labelElapsedTime.Text = "---";
            // 
            // labelActivity
            // 
            this.labelActivity.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
            this.labelActivity.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(184)))), ((int)(((byte)(28)))));
            this.labelActivity.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.labelActivity.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(566, 609);
            this.labelActivity.Name = "labelActivity";
            this.labelActivity.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(77, 66);
            this.labelActivity.TabIndex = 35;
            this.labelActivity.Text = "---";
            // 
            // ucRobot
            // 
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
            this.Controls.Add(this.labelActivity);
            this.Controls.Add(this.labelElapsedTime);
            this.Controls.Add(this.labelCurrent);
            this.Controls.Add(this.labelVoltage);
            this.Controls.Add(this.labelLoad);
            this.Controls.Add(this.labelSpeed);
            this.Controls.Add(this.labelChargeLevel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label8);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label7);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label6);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label5);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.labelTemperature);
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
            this.Name = "ucRobot";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1307, 714);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.ucRobot_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
        #endregion
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelTemperature;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label6;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label7;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label8;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelChargeLevel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelSpeed;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelLoad;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelVoltage;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelCurrent;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelElapsedTime;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelActivity;
    }
}


Probably I tried every possible settings about auto size etc. but I cant try again with your comments. I hope you can help me.
